# I can't seem to connect the HomeActivity to LogInActivity. The error said ActivityNotFound. No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android

Here's my LogInActivity

```
public class LogInActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginactivity);

Button launch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        launch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
         public void onClick(View v) {
           EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
           EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
           TextView loginTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

           String sUserName = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
           String sPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

            if(sUserName.equals("numlock") && sPassword.equals("numlock")){
                Intent i = new Intent();
                startActivity(i);
            }
             else {
                loginTextView.setText("Login failed. Username and/or password doesn't match.");
                 }
            }
        }); 
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

and here's my HomeActivity

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homeactivity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are both activities declared on the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the new activity in AndroidManifest.xml file, like this:

```
<activity
  android:name=".HomeActivity"
  android:label="Home activity">
</activity>
```

Comment: I have one, but it still wont start the next activity.

Comment: Then the problem is in what Vineet mentioned. Just change Intent i = new Intent() to Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, HomeActivity.class)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
startActivity(i);
```

you have not set activity to be launched here...

make sure there is entry in the manifest file ..

Comment: I've added this on the latter part: public void onClick(View v)
     {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
     }